# UISplitViewController - Resize views by dragging the divider line

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I thought it was a basic feature of UISplitViewController to allow resizing master/detail views by dragging the divider line. After reading the documentation, I found that it isn't possible on iOS apps. However, I did find apps on iOS that have SplitView's with draggable divider for resizing the master/detail view.

Has anyone done it? If yes, could you please help me with some pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168124/resize-master-and-detail-view-controllers-in-a-split-view-controller  , ur question seems to be a similar one.

Comment: Any app with a draggable divider isn't using `UISplitViewController`. You need to write or find a custom split view controller that supports a draggable divider.

Comment: @andyPaul - I did a research prior to posting and did notice that post. My question is different as I'm looking to resize the view by dragging the divider line. I know that I can use preferredPrimaryColumnFraction for changing the view widths but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: @rmaddy. I thought so. Wonder, if you know of any such open source controls?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your query but a small code using adding just a simple `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to your `MasterViewController's` view.

If you are iOS 8.0 or later, you can use `minimumPrimaryColumnWidth` and `maximumPrimaryColumnWidth` , alongwith `preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction`.

I have added left and right Swipe gesture recognizer to the View of MasterViewController.

```
@IBAction func swipeGesture(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {


    if sender.direction == .left {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.splitViewController?.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth  = 200.0
            self.splitViewController?.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 0.0
            self.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320.0
        }
    } else if sender.direction == .right {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.splitViewController?.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth  = 200.0
            self.splitViewController?.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = 1.0
            self.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320.0
        }
    }

}
```

You can also try with pan Gesture too, as listed below to get fine control of the touch movements.

```
 let maximumPossibleWidth:CGFloat = 320.0
var beganPoint:CGFloat = 320.0
@IBAction func panGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){




    if sender.state == .began {
        //Began
        beganPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view).x
        return
    }

    if sender.state == .changed {

        let currentPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view).x
        let fraction = currentPoint / maximumPossibleWidth

        if beganPoint > currentPoint {
            //left
                self.splitViewController?.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth  = 100.0
                self.splitViewController?.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = fraction
                self.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320.0
        }else {
            //right
                self.splitViewController?.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth  = 100.0
                self.splitViewController?.preferredPrimaryColumnWidthFraction = fraction
                self.splitViewController?.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 320.0
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice snippet. I'm writing a custom splitView to get what I need.